# Geospatial distance metric that includes heading differences

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, geospatial

I've been trying to search for a standard metric that includes both distance and difference in heading and haven't been very successful - hoping I could get some insight here and maybe help my search a bit more, or even just tell me something obvious that I'm missing..

I'm working with a bunch of lat/long points that also have a particular heading and I'd like to find the closest point on another set while also matching the heading as much as possible. I've been using sklearn's [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) with the [haverine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric) metric to get the nearest neighbor between these two sets to some success but I'd like to add in heading in both sets of points to try to minimize both distance and heading for the metric.

It looks like I can't use custom callables for sklearn's Ball Tree and KD Tree algorithms anyway so I'd be okay with the brute-force algorithm if need be.

I guess what I'm asking is:

1. Is there a standard distance metric that includes heading difference that I could reuse?
2. Is there a better approach to minimizing both the distance and heading between two sets of data?

One alternative, if I can't figure this out, is to just filter my candidate set of points (w/ heading) to only points with a heading within some tolerance of each source point's heading but that seems kinda cumbersome and clunky. Any other suggestions welcomed though!

Comment: I would probably split up the data. Define what you want to be considered "Close enough" as far as heading offset goes. Half it then split up the data into bins where the heading is in the appropriate bin. IE if you want within +-20 degres, split it up into 0-10, 10-20, 20-30..., then build KD trees for the points in each bin. If you are looking for say 5 degree heading, Then you'd need to check the 350-360 bin, the 0-10 bin, and the 10-20 bin. Real issue is there's ambiguity. Do you prioritize heading match or nearest point?

Comment: You could also triangulate the points. It's relatively quick to find the nearest point in a triangulation. And once you have that, you can quickly check the nearby headings. If heading is more of a priority, you could sort the points by heading, find the closest point, then work outwards in direcitons (circular list) until you find one that is "close enough). Again, the real issue is how much weight you put on angle similarity compared to distance similarity. When is a point that is X distance away and within Y degrees worst/better than one that is within M distance away and within N degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've also been thinking what the weights might be (was thinking maybe something like equal weighting after both has been normalized but that's probably not necessary for my needs) and I'd probably want to prioritize heading similarity at a high level. This could also mean, to simplify the problem, to only consider  the set of points that are +- 20 degrees and get the best distance similarity from that.

Comment: Yea, then my first comment should be fairly good way to go.  Though there is still the question of something like this: point A is off by 5 degrees, but 1.5X as far away as point B, which is only off by 3 degrees. Though doesn't matter if you just go with the "as long as they are within X degrees, just use the closest" route. Of course, perhaps the closest is actually off by 21 degrees. Though in that case, i'd probably just keep a KD tree of every point, as well as those within 10 degres of each other.

Comment: Oh another possibility, use a KD tree with an extra unrolled dimension for heading, just include one point at the actual heading, and two more at `+- 360` degrees. IE: `1` would be `-359, 1, 361` and `359` would be `-1, 359 and 719`. Downside here as that you may need to scale the distances a bit to avoid that dimension being much higher or lower in weight that it should be. Source of that idea: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51908/nearest-neighbor-algorithm-for-circular-dimensions